# How do you dynamically pass in a cucumber feature file to a maven project Using the command prompt?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, bamboo, x-ray

I've created maven project with selenium and cucumber. I'm trying to use jira X-ray in a continuous integration setup. Basically I take exported feature files and want to execute them on a command line using bamboo.

I think my main problem is I'm not sure how to feed in feature files to a compiled maven project that has the step definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I have features defined in `src/test/resources/shouty`

If I only want to run the `location.feature` using Maven, then I can use the command

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/shouty/location.feature"
```

What you want to do is to specify the feature in the CI job using Maven as above.

Comment: can you please share pom.xml for this, as in my case it's not running anything.